# Using javax.mail to send to multiple recipients

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I've got the following...

```
msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
```

Which works fine but when I attempt to add this multiple times (with different variables for `to`) it only sends to the last statement. I've also attempted sending something like `email1@gmail.com :email2@gmail.com` as the `to` variable but this throws back an error.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I'd send mail to multiple recipients using JUST one e-mail and not multiple e-mails using `javax.mail`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`msg.setRecipients()` takes an array of addresses as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Use Message's subclass - MimeMessage. It implments the `setRecipients(Message.RecipientType type, Address[] addresses)`  method.

Furthermore, you could choose which specific message you need to use: `IMAPMessage, POP3Message, SMTPMessage`.